# Defining window round corners in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm trying to add round corners to my window's desktop app, while using .NET MAUI.

I've searched and found many ways to do it in WPF, but none have worked in Maui.

I've tried to overwrite the create window method but while I can change the size, there is no property in window to change corner radius.

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

    const int newWidth = 1000;
    const int newHeight = 600;

    window.Width = newWidth;
    window.Height = newHeight;

    window.MinimumHeight = newHeight;
    window.MinimumWidth = newWidth;

    //doesn't exist
    window.CornerRadius = "10,10,10,10";

    return window;
}
```

If I try to wrap my content page in a border, I only get the content in a border, not the window.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you test it on the Windows 10? The window will default have round corners on the windows 11. And according to the [official document about the round corners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners#how-to-opt-in-to-rounded-corners), you can't set it with the value you want. It can only be small or big round corner.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on windows 10, i guess that's the problem